# Filling dates in dataframe with triple index

Tags: python, pandas, date, multi-index, fillna

I know that a similiar question to this one has been made, but the solution works when you have only one categorical variable. I have two of those, and `MultiIndexes` have always been difficult for me to work with. The thing is, I've got the following dataframe:

```
 Date        Product    eCommerce   Sales
12-10-2018      A           1        10
12-12-2018      A           0        7
12-13-2018      A           1        4
12-15-2018      A           1        2
12-15-2018      A           0        2
12-11-2018      B           1        8
12-13-2018      B           1        6
```

So I need to know sales with and without eCommerce for every date **and  fill the dates that are not appearing with zero sales**. My desired output would be:

```
 Date        Product    eCommerce   Sales
12-10-2018      A           1        10
12-11-2018      A           1        0
12-12-2018      A           1        0
12-13-2018      A           1        4
12-14-2018      A           1        0
12-15-2018      A           1        2

12-12-2018      A           0        7
12-13-2018      A           0        0
12-14-2018      A           0        0
12-15-2018      A           0        2

12-11-2018      B           1        8
12-12-2018      B           1        0
12-13-2018      B           1        6
```

Note: It's just one DataFrame, I just added the spaces to differentiate the indexes.

**So in the original DataFrame 12-11 and 12-14 are missing for eCommerce Sales of Product A, 12-13 and 12-14 for non-eCommerce Sales of Product A and 12-12 is missing for eCommerce Sales of product B**

The thing is, I managed to achieve what I want, through a very inefficient loop that takes about 25 minutes to run:

```
df_full= pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for sku in df['Product'].unique():

    aux=df.loc[df['Product']==sku]
    dates= pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=aux.Date.min(), end=aux.Date.max(),freq='D'),columns=['Date'])

    df3 = df.loc[df['id_prod']==sku].merge(dates,
                                                   how='outer',left_on='Date',
                                                   right_on='Date').sort_values(by='Date')

    df3.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
    df_full= df_full.append(df3)
```

I'm quite confident that I can do this in a vectorized way, that should take less time (I have 2,300 products for 290 possible dates). Do you know how can I achieve this?

Edit: Added bolded text with better explanation of the problem

Comment: Do you need to ffill?  What about df.groupby(['Date', 'Product', 'eCommerce'], as_index=False).sum()?

Comment: Tagging on to my first comment, I don't see what you are actually doing with the data.  Is this just an exercise is sorting by date and eCommerce?

Comment: I need to fill the dates I don't have with zero sales. So, in my original DataFrame I have  neCommerce sales on 12-10 and on 12-12, thus I need to fill 12-11 with zero sales. (And every other day that's missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single `DatetimeIndex` then `groupby` + `resample.asfreq()`, (can use sum for numeric columns) as the date range is group dependent.

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.set_index('Date')

df.groupby(['Product', 'eCommerce'], sort=False).Sales.resample('D').sum().reset_index()
```

If you have many columns you want to fill with zero then:

```
(df.groupby(['Product', 'eCommerce'], sort=False)
    .resample('D').sum()
    .drop(columns=['Product', 'eCommerce'])
    .reset_index())
```

#### Output:

```
   Product  eCommerce       Date  Sales
0        A          1 2018-12-10     10
1        A          1 2018-12-11      0
2        A          1 2018-12-12      0
3        A          1 2018-12-13      4
4        A          1 2018-12-14      0
5        A          1 2018-12-15      2
6        A          0 2018-12-12      7
7        A          0 2018-12-13      0
8        A          0 2018-12-14      0
9        A          0 2018-12-15      2
10       B          1 2018-12-11      8
11       B          1 2018-12-12      0
12       B          1 2018-12-13      6
```

Comment: I have a simple follow-up question, though: my actual DataFrame has other variables, like unit price, or sale price how could I keep those variables for the non-zero Sales rows? Edit: seems I answered to myself: I performed a left join between my new dataframe and the old dataframe, then filled `nan` with 0.

Comment: @JuanC See my update. This will resample every column. It also resamples the grouping columns, which we don't want, so that's why the `drop` is there. They'll show up after the reset_index anyway. If needed, you could remove the `.fillna(0)` if you don't want to fill every column, or need to fill other columns with different values.